# vue-router | Laravel Организация динамических маршрутов

Tags: laravel, vue.js, spa, vue-router

Я пишу соц сеть с использованием vue & laravel. Я встал в тупик с генерацией пользовательских id. По бизнес логике, в соц сети может зарегистрироваться пользователь. И получить свой уникальный идентификатор(id). И по этому id можно найти его профиль в соц сети.

### Проблема в том что я не знаю как динамически с vue. Подгружать пользователей.

```
{
    path: '/mypage:id',
    name: 'Mypage',
    component: Mypage,
    meta: {
        auth: false
    }
},
```

У меня есть route. Он динамический и он может подгружать пользователей. Но как создать такое 
API которое будет обслуживать работу этого route. Генерацию внутри SPA как сделать я понимаю. Но как сделать эту генерацию на конкретные URI адреса которые генерируются. При пользовательском вводе в браузере.

Для полной ясности пример того поведения которое я хочу увидеть. 
У нас зарегистрировано 100 пользователей. Они получают id от 1 до 100. Если мы в браузере пишем. localhost/100 нам загружается последний зарегистрированный пользователь. Если мы пишем localhost/101 нам загружается страница 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, слэш поставить надо после айди. Это ж переменная.

```
{
    path: '/mypage/:id',
    name: 'Mypage',
    component: Mypage,
    meta: {
        auth: false
    }
},
```

Далее, в компоненте указываешь в хуке роута

```
beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
  async next(vm => { // поскольку у тебя нет ещё доступа к `this`, `vm` и будет тем `this`, когда ты уже зайдёшь в роут
    await axios.get('/api/id); // тут ты забираешь по айдишнику юзера
  });
}
```

По поводу асинка, возможно придётся его не у некста ставить, а прям у хука. Но это ты посмотри уже сам. В общем, схема примерно такая. [Документация по роутеру тут](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards)